# .exe package creation through IExpress for silent installation

Tags: installation, exe, silent, iexpress

I have a .exe file and i basically want to run it silently without any pop-ups. My question is  how can i do this through Iexpress?
I can add my .exe file in the Iexpress but then what commands should i use in the  use in the command line field to make my final .exe run silently?

Answer (score 6):

During the IExpress wizard, there's a screen titled *Show window*. If you choose *Hidden*, then your executable will run completely silently. This corresponds to the `ShowInstallProgramWindow` option in the SED file, where:

```
0 = Default
1 = Hidden
2 = Minimized
3 = Maximized
```

Depending on what your executable does, you may need to pass additional options to it to make it run *non-interactively* (eg `/verysilent`), but it depends on what type of executable it is.